# Pappos Theorem and distance of points

Tags: geometry

Let be $CDEB$ a parallelogramm.
$F,G$ any points on the inner lines $DE$, $CB$ like in the picture.

[image]

How can I show, that $CJ$=$KE$ ?
I thought about using Pappos Theorem, which states, that $H$ and $I$ are colinear..
but how do I proceed for the distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be the intersection of the diagonals $CE$, $BD$. By Pappus' theorem the points $CG \cap FD = H$, $CE \cap BD=M$, and $FE \cap BG=I$ are collinear.

We see now that $C$ is symmetric to $E$ and $J$ is symmetric to $K$ with respect to $M$. In particular $CJ=KE$.